# Disabling navigation buttons in web2py

Tags: html, web2py

For my application on web2py, I am using pagination and displaying 5 entries/page. I would like to disable the "Previous' button on the first page of the entries and the 'Next' button on the last page of the entries.
My Previous button-

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href={{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)-1})}}>Previous</a>
```

The controller code is-

```
def viewallposts():
         if not request.vars.page:
                 redirect(URL(vars={'page':1}))
         else:
                 page = int(request.vars.page)
         start = (page-1)*5
         end = page*5
         user = auth.user_id
         image=db().select(db.posts.ALL, orderby=~db.posts.created_on, limitby=(start,end))
         return dict(user=user, image=image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Controller` the `redirect(URL(vars={'page':1}))` should be `0` not `1`, also you have to define `page=page` in the `return dict` :

```
def viewallposts():
         if not request.vars.page:
                 redirect(URL(vars={'page':0}))
         else:
                 page = int(request.vars.page)
         start = (page-1)*5
         end = page*5
         user = auth.user_id
         image=db().select(db.posts.ALL, orderby=~db.posts.created_on, limitby=(start,end))
         return dict(user=user, image=image, page=page)
```

In your `View`:

```
{{if page:}}
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)-1})}}">Previous</a>
{{pass}}
{{if len(image)>=5:}}
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)+1})}}">Next</a>
{{pass}}
```

Comment: @Pranav Great! Happy I could help. Please click to accept the answer.